# How to set an appointment to other users on outlook?

Tags: c#, email, outlook

Let's say I log in to the OS with administrator account and have permissions to set appointments to other users, without sending a mail.

How can I do it in the code?
I could only find examples working with AppontmentItem and set an appointment to the local machine's outlook.  How can I do it for external users?

Many thanks in advance!

```
    private static void AddAppointment()
    {


            Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application(); // creates new outlook app
            Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppointment =
                (Outlook.AppointmentItem) outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
                // creates a new appointment

            oAppointment.Subject = "Enquiry Changes made to john enquiry"; // set the subject
            oAppointment.Body = "This is where the appointment body of the appointment is written"; // set the body
            oAppointment.Location = "Nicks Desk!"; // set the location
            oAppointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
            oAppointment.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
            oAppointment.ReminderSet = true; // Set the reminder
            oAppointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15; // reminder time
            oAppointment.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh; // appointment importance
            oAppointment.BusyStatus = Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;
            oAppointment.Save();
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = oAppointment.ForwardAsVcal();
    }
```

Comment: Did you already try anything? If so, please show what you've done. The least that will do is show us the API that you're considering. Without it, this question will be closed as either being too broad or as looking for a recommended off-site resource or as lacking the problematic code in question.

Comment: Thanks - I've added it to the original message.

Comment: if you need to be setting things in their calendar without sending them an invite, you  need to be talking to the server (so, Exchange, probably) and not Outlook. ALl you'll be able to do with your local outlook is send them a invite (i.e. a mail). If you are OK sending them something (which your ForwardAsVcal suggests, even though your main text suggests otherwise) then you have to do something with that mailItem! (e.g. send it).

Comment: But how can I send it to other user's exchange?  Currently, this code set an appointment on mine...

Comment: I'm not sure if impersonation is a feature in the Outlook API, it doesn't look like it in a few Google searches. If you have the credentials of the user, you can do a simple `runas`. But it sounds more like you're actually trying to use impersonation, which is part of (e.g.) the Exchange Web Service API. Search for `ExchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId` to get started.

Comment: And what ExchangeService is ?  As you can see, i'm using interop.outlook ref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder() to open other user's Calendar folder, then create an appointment using MAPIFolder.Items.Add.

Comment: Thanks!   Great link here:  http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/