# using Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppointment for a specific user

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, outlook

I've done some research on this and not been able to find an example for my exact problem, although there are a lot so apologies if I've missed it.

I have some code that will add an appointment to my Outlook calendar automatically, and then send an email to the recipient. however now I want to be able to add it to a public calendar which is on a generic username... so the code I use only adds it to the user calendar that is logged in.

heres the code that does this on the press of a button:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = "Test Name";
        DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2015, 4, 2);
        DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2015, 4, 2);


        Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application(); // creates new outlook app
        Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem); // creates a new appointment

        oAppointment.Subject = "Enquiry Changes made to " + name + "'s enquiry"; // set the subject
        oAppointment.Body = "This is where the appointment body of the appointment is written"; // set the body
        oAppointment.Location = "The location"; // set the location
        oAppointment.Start = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate); // Set the start date 
        oAppointment.End = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate); // End date 
        oAppointment.ReminderSet = true; // Set the reminder
        oAppointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15; // reminder time
        oAppointment.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh; // appointment importance
        oAppointment.BusyStatus = Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;

        oAppointment.Save();

        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = oAppointment.ForwardAsVcal(); 
        // email address to send to 
        mailItem.To = "genericemail@provider.com";

        // send 
        mailItem.Send();
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.... and to clarify, I want to be able to add an appointment to a specific users calendar, not the user that is currently logged onto the machine.

here is a link extremely similar but also does not have an accepted answered: [How to set an appointment to other users on outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365604/how-to-set-an-appointment-to-other-users-on-outlook)

Comment: Um, the other question that you link to _does_ have an answer.

Comment: its not been accepted and the link provided is no use... ive tried using this: 
https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/
but it does not work

Comment: I don't understand. The answer on that thread _has_ been accepted, and 
Dmitry Streblechenko is _the_ number one guru when it comes to interfacing with Outlook. He's the author of Outlook Spy, a great program for investigating the MAPI structures used by Outlook. http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm

Comment: By the way, maybe your problem is a lack of permissions. To add an appointment to another user's calendar you need to have full editing rights, not just viewing rights.

Comment: I understand how to access to calendar, I have a separate application ive created before I tried to add appointments, im now looking at the ExchangeService, if you post the an answer with more information than the link provided on the previous post, then ill happily accept it, it may be because I do not understand what its doing.. in particular I get an error for the "OutlookApp" this is in red and doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the Outlook Exchange API solved my issue:

```
//This will initialize the exchange web service object
        ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
        //Setting service URL
        try
        {
            exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl("emailaddress@domain.co.uk");
        }
        catch (AutodiscoverLocalException ex)
        {
            //If auto discover URL fails mannualy configure the exchange service URL
            exchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://yourexchangename/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password", "domain");
        //OR
        exchangeService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(exchangeService);
        appointment.Subject = "Sample subject";
        appointment.Body = "sample Body";
        appointment.Start = new DateTime(2015, 4, 1, 8, 0, 0);
        appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(9.5);
        // Occurs every weeks on Tuesday and Thursday
        appointment.Save();
```

this bit of code will try 3 ways to connect to the specific user account, in my case this is a generic user where a shared calendar is kept. the second part of the code will add the appointment directly to your calendar.... hope this helps people

Answer (score 0):

I am glad that you have found my article helpful.

To add a new appointment item to the public (i.e. chared) calendar you need to get the shared folder first. To get the job done, you need to use the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class which returns a Folder object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. For example:

```
Sub ResolveName()  
  Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
  Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
  Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder  
  Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
  Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Dan Wilson")  
  myRecipient.Resolve  
  If myRecipient.Resolved Then  
    Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
  End If  
End Sub 

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
  Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder  
  Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)  
  CalendarFolder.Display  
End Sub
```

Also you may find the [OpenSharedFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867648(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class whic opens a shared folder referenced through a URL or file name. This method is used to access the following shared folder types:

- Webcal calendars (webcal://mysite/mycalendar)
- RSS feeds (feed://mysite/myfeed)
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation folders (stssync://mysite/myfolder)
- iCalendar calendar (.ics) files
- vCard contact (.vcf) files
- Outlook message (.msg) files

Then you can use the Items property to add a new appointment item using the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861028(v=office.15).aspx) method.

As an alternative way consider using EWS, see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information.